# php global variable not working

Tags: php, global-variables, global

Good morning everyone!  I have a php project that I'm working on and can't figure out why the global variable is not working correctly.  The project uses several files as laid out below:

### main.php

```
...
function externalCall() {
  if (! call_user_func('second_function')) {
    ...
  }
}
...
externalCall();
```

### second.php

```
$MODULE='second';
...
echo ':'.$MODULE.':';
...
function second_function() {
    global $MODULE;
    echo ':'.$MODULE.':';
}
```

Now the 'echo' statement in the 'second_function' just prints a null value instead of the assigned value 'second', whereas the preceeding 'echo' prints out 'second' correctly.  Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: Dunno what all those `...` are doing, but: https://eval.in/470489 You're probably not defining `$MODULE` before `externalCall()` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply AbraCadaver! The ... are to indicate other code.  And $MODULE is one of the first declarations in the file.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: That's not how you show it.  The link clearly shows it works.

Comment: @Roland the output is :second::: which indicates the first echo is being called before the function declaration.

Comment: @AbraCadaver the output above is showing the declaration is above the function.  My output is confirming.

Comment: `$MODULE='second';` MUST COME BEFORE `externalCall();` or it has no value when `second_function()` is called.

Comment: @AbraCadaver  ahhh!  I didn't realize that!  I'll have to rethink the structure of this then.  If you want to list that as the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: FWIW find a way without globals.

Comment: And if you do, you may want to list that the global has to come before ANY reference to a function that uses the global.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do.  Pass the value directly to the function.